# How to change user role via command line in Magento 2?

Tags: role, change

How to change existing user role to Administrator via command line? Or it should be in sql? Or maybe programmatically?

Best regards,
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

It should be done via the Backend. Simply edit the Admin Use, assign it the new role and save it.

Comment: I need to change it via command line. No backend (admin panel)

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock the admin user in the magento by command line :

```
bin/magento admin:user:unlock {username}
```

Comment: This command only unlock account, not upgrade the role